# Ignore apostrophes, commas, hyphens, etc in a search

Tags: mysql, sql

Example of the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `content`
RLIKE "[[:<:]]didnt[[:>:]]"
```

The problem is, when I search for things like "didnt", columns with "didn't" (with an apostrophe) arent found. And if I were to search for "didn't", columns with "didnt" (without an apostrophe) arent found.

What change do I need to make so that it ignores apostrophes, commas, hyphens, etc, and gives results regardless of if there are/arent apostrophes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I made some changes.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try with an `|options`

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
(content RLIKE "[[:<:]]didnt[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]didn't[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]didn..t[[:>:]]|ETC)"
```

source: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/regexp_rlike

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested replace functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE
  replace(replace(replace(`content`, '\'', ''), ',', ''), '-', '')
  RLIKE "[[:<:]]didnt[[:>:]]"
```